# Divots in concrete from carpet tack

Tags: concrete, basement, vinyl-flooring

I'm pulling up carpet tack from a concrete basement floor using the techniques in these videos: [vid1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=molpBYAKUPU), [vid2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV4xSfZ75Gc)... the technique isn't perfect and I'm still getting the small divots here and there.  How concerned should I be about those divots if I'm aiming to put vinyl flooring down eventually?  Do the divots definitely have to be filled before laying down flooring?

Comment: The guy in the first video says "that's a size I don't have to fill before I put the floor down"... Are you actually laying sheet vinyl, or are you putting down laminate wood flooring? If vinyl, are you planning on any underlayment? A thin, flexible vinyl _may_ show that divot, especially over time. A wood floor or solid underlayment would span it with no issue.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot avoid a divot when pulling nails out of concrete small divots I use epoxy filler larger or a large number I use a self leveling compound or hydraulic cement. Vinyl flooring will show divots so they need to be filled.